# Выборка по месяцу через BETWEEN (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

В БД **дата** хранится в текстовом поле, в формате вида: `17.07.2016`
Делаю выборку:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`sms_send_exam`)
FROM
  cartoteka 
WHERE
  `date_exam` BETWEEN '01.07.2000' AND '30.07.2025'
```

Получаю 18 (так на самом деле)

Когда делаю так:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`sms_send_exam`) 
FROM
  cartoteka
WHERE
  `date_exam` BETWEEN '29.07.2000' AND '30.07.2025'
```

Получаю уже 11(!), это неверный результат.
Или для BETWEEN надо определённый формат данных, типа ?

Дополнение. Пробовал запрос

```
SELECT
  COUNT(`sms_send_exam`) 
FROM
  cartoteka
WHERE
  `date_exam` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.07.2000', '%d.%m.%Y') AND
  STR_TO_DATE('30.07.2025', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Не помогло тоже. И выдаёт почему-то 9(!)

---

**Дополнение_2**(!)
А вот такой вариант, через **LIKE** (*проверил - рабочий*), он страшный или нормальный?

```
$sms_counter_month = mysql_query (
  "SELECT COUNT(`sms_send_exam`)
   FROM ".$userstable."
   WHERE `date_exam` LIKE '%".$month.".".$year."'", $db);
```

Comment: А если сделать `WHERE STR_TO_DATE('date_exam', '%d.%m.%Y')  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.07.2000', '%d.%m.%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('30.07.2025', '%d.%m.%Y')` ? ( только кавычки у date_exam правильные поставьте)

Comment: А зачем вы дату храните в текстовом поле. Сделайте поле типа дата и будет вам счастье

Comment: Вы в первом дополнении пропустили приведение date_exam к формату даты, вероятно поэтому Ваш запрос не работает.

Comment: @Mike - ПО составлялось без ТЗ, В просьбе о ПО стояло лишь отправка смс по дате внесённой работником. Но сами знаете, как это бывает. Через месяцев 4 у руководителя (им же лишь бы всё проверять), родилась хотелка, получения мини-отчётности по отправленным смс, по месяцам, а переводить дату (менять поле) для меня сложнее, чем спрограммировать на LIKE. Или конвертация полей, из типа в тип, быстра и безболезненна для БД?
Как-то не приходилось баловаться такой методой.

Comment: Переделайте поле на правильный тип

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас дата хранится в виде строки '29.07.2000', а строки сравниваются сначала, т.е. получается вы сначала сравниваете дни, потом месяцы и лишь потом годы. Таким образом дата '29.07.2000' у вас будет больше, чем '19.07.2016'. Для того, чтобы предотвратить это, лучше хранить дату в календарном типе данных `DATE` или на худой конец в виде строки '2000.07.29', когда у вас год идет первым, за ним месяц и лишь потом день.

Ваш запрос с `LIKE` тоже имеет право на существование и довольно часто используется, хотя повторю с датой было бы гораздо более эффективно использоваться календарный тип. К сожалению, у вас тут шаблон % идет в начале строки, поэтому если даже вы проиндексируете её - это вам не сильно поможет, так как строки сравниваются с начала, с первых символов.